# How do i connect to vga monitors to a hdmi laptop

Tags: display, cable

I want to connect my two monitors that have vga to my laptop that has hdmi but im no sure what cables to buy, im really  confused about what cables to buy.

I was thinking  buying a vga to hdmi and then another cable vga to a usb. Can anyone give some advice please about what cables i have to buy to set up my office.

thank you so much

Comment: You can convert a digital signal to analog signal easy enough.  Why does your plan include converting a VGA to USB that doesn't make sense.  HDMI to VGA cables exists.  If your laptop does not have two HDMI ports then you can't hook up both displays.  The simplest solution to get around that limitation would be to purchase a docking station that supports.  Those types of docking stations won't be cheap though.

Comment: Hardware purchasing recommendations are off topic on Super User.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time answering my question. My laptop only have one HDMI port so there is nothing I can do without a docking station?.  All I wanted to do was to display what is on my laptop  in my two monitors.

Comment: @dragon200 - Like I said, your laptop would need 2 HDMI ports, to do what you describe without a docking station.  VGA to USB adaptors cost nearly as much as the docking station itself ($50 USD).  There exists Universal USB 3.0 docking stations, with 2 VGA ports, that will accomplish your goals (less then $100).  If you add the HDMI to VGA cable which is at least ($25 USD) you are better of with the docking station.  As correctly point out both the (USB VGA/HDMI) adaptors and the USB 3.0 docking stations won't work with Linux.

Answer (score 1):

VGA to HDMI will work most certainly, although VGA doesn't carry audio like HDMI does. Probably irrelevant if we're only talking computer monitors.

As for the VGA -> USB, if you're running Linux, I wouldn't bother as such things are a pain there. On Windows though, it's likely to work.